# I want to save Boolean state to user profile in Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have successfully saved the user email to my firebase database but I want to also save a state to that particular user in another view when they press save. This is all a test app to wrap my head around using Firebase Database and User Authentication.

So right now when the user registers with the app they are logged into the database.

```
class SignupViewController: UIViewController {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().root

    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameEntryField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameEntryField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailEntryField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordEntryField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailEntryField.text!, password: passwordEntryField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {

                //Show SVProgressHUD
                SVProgressHUD.show()

                //save User to Database
                self.ref.child("users").child((user?.user.uid)!).setValue(self.emailEntryField.text!)

                //Dismiss SVProgressHUD
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                //move to info view controller
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToInfo", sender: self)

            } else {

                print("Signup Unsuccessul")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

[image]

And on another view I am attempting to save a boolean state to the current users profile after signing up, but I know I am likely not doing it right. As you can see right now it only saves one instance so if I register another user and save the "stylist" boolean as true it will overwrite the current false state. But I want each user who registers to have a stylist boolean state associated with their account.

[image]

```
class InfoViewController: UIViewController {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    var isStylist : Bool = false

    @IBAction func stylistSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if isStylist == false {
            isStylist = true
            print(isStylist)
        } else {
            isStylist = false
            print(isStylist)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func saveUserProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

            //show SVProgressHUD
            SVProgressHUD.show()

            //save Stylist state to Database
            self.ref.child("stylists").setValue(self.isStylist)

            //dismiss SVProgressHUD
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            //Segue to ProfileViewController
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "infoToProfile", sender: self)

        } else {
            print("Error")
        }

    }
}
```

All help would be greatly appreciated or if anyone has any links to good resources. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only save a key-value for the uid , but you want to save a dictionary like this

```
let newUserInfo = [
    "email":self.emailEntryField.text!,
    "state":true
]  

self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(newUserInfo, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

}
```

after this you can use the path **users->uid->state** to alter that value

```
self.ref.child("users").child("\(user!.uid)/state").setValue(true)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, so I am having a bit of trouble implementing this. Where should I be inserting this code?

Comment: inside **Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail**

Comment: Okay so I have it setup like this but now I am getting some errors. See above.

Comment: I figured out how to get the code to work but now I am having an issue with altering the value using users->uid->state

Comment: Using the edited version I still get the error, "Type 'User?' has no member 'uid'"

Comment: any chance you know what could be causing my error?

Comment: @Trlewi it's being updated --> **user.providerData[0].uid** look here to new properties of Firuser https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser

Comment: this resource is in ObjectiveC is there a way to see the Swift code

Comment: look to var names , you can write and autocomplete helps you , for sorry there is no toggle for swift in firebase

Comment: thank you for all your help with this I am slowly getting a grasp on all of this